# Why does my Azure Hybrid Connection show a "Status Unknown"?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-hybrid-connections, azure-relay

So...about 5pm 2 nights ago, all 14 of my listeners on my Azure Service Bus dropped.  So I logged in to my on-prem SQL Server to check on my Hybrid Connections and both of them showed a status of "Status Unknown".  I can't find anything on the internet about this specific status.
Nothing changed on my SQL Server other than the fact that I've pegged the RAM....it's at 100% usage.

If I go to the Azure Portal, navigate to either of my Hybrid Connection Overview pages and click on the "Hybrid Connection Url", I get the following message in the browser:

```
"error": {
    "code":"TokenMissingOrInvalid",
    "message":"MissingToken: Relay security token is required. TrackingId:*SOME GUID*, SystemTracker:*SERVICE BUS NAME*:*HYBRID CONNECTION NAME*, Timestamp:2021-08-04T04:19:16"}
}
```

Now....I didn't change anything on my Hybrid Connection configurations.  I haven't changed anything about tokens.  I have no idea what's going on other than my Azure App Services have been down for 2 days, now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: I suggest you raise a ticket with Microsoft

Comment: Created a case with MS.  I'll update once this is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft support led me to this [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-hybrid-connections/ba-p/392387) where I found the following information:

**Make Sure that the Date and Time are Correct**

The Hybrid Connection Manager connects to Azure Relay using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) on port 443. If there's a problem with your SSL handshake or connection, it will break your Hybrid Connection. If you find that your Hybrid Connection works initially, and then it stops working after about 10 minutes, that's a sign that you need to check the date and time on the machine running the Hybrid Connection Manager. Make sure they are correct because if they're not, your SSL connection may not work.

Well...the time on my server was off by about 16 minutes b/c of a group policy that I had never bothered to fix b/c I don't know anything about group policies.  So I looked up how to fix the server's clock and, once that done, resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an authentication error where a token might not be generating when you are trying to make a call to the underlying On prem server

You can refer the [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000499/testing-an-azure-hybrid-connection-using-soapui) for ServiceBusAuthorization and still if you are facing the issue kindly raise a ticket with [MS-Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html)

Comment: Created a case with MS.  I'll update once this is resolved.